# QtDesigner: Setting fixed size of QLabel

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer

I have a fixed size label on a QtDesigner form. The label is used to display images, let's assume it's used to display thumbnails of 100x100 px.

I can set the size of the label but when I put the label in some layout manager the labels get resized to take the whole space. Even if I do it through the Form > Layout in a Grid. The size of the labels is shrunk.

I believe this is some corner case as labels are not often used to do such things (although they are meant to be able to display images). Is there a workaround to avoid the size of the labels changing when placed in the layout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set horizontal and vertical [size policies](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) to Fixed or set the maximum [height](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#maximumHeight-prop) and [width](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#maximumWidth-prop) additionally. Either in code or in Designer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, had to set size policy to Fixed and min and max size